# OpenCV - FLANN algorithm does't obtain enough matching point

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

I'm a neophyte of computer vision.
I'm using this algorithm http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html proposed by Open CV in order to calculate some matching points between 2 scenes of the same environment (aerial view of a city) after a roto-translation of the camera that takes the images.
The camera and the environment are both simulated (so no changing of brightness, no distortions and so on)
Obviously the frame rate is high enough in order to have images in large part overlapped.
After that I have to use this point to calculate the Affine transformation matrix that describes the movement done by the camera (the height from which the images are taken doesn't change over time).
So I need, for every couple of images, at least 2 matching points..
My problem is that often the matching points are less than 3.. 
Does some robust method exist that works better for my purposes?
thanks

Comment: Are you using the code you linked? It is supposed to be robust (at least it should work in the situation you described).

Comment: yes, exactly the same. It's robust, in the sense that the matching are always exact, but the strange thing is that even if the image makes a very little movement and changes only for few pixels (not more than ten let's say) the matchings are very few!

Comment: How many matches do you have before the filtering (commented with `//-- Draw only "good" matches`)?

Comment: with no movements of the camera: about 312; with small movements: about 290.
the problem is that if I increase the min distance it finds wrong matchings

Comment: It means that you have around 300 feature points that you match, and in the end all but three are filtered out, right? And if you draw all of the matchings (without filtering anything), do you have good matches? In which proportion?

Comment: using the same code as that given by opencv the matchings are all good but often less than 3.
if i try to modify the code changing 2*min_dist into 2*min_dist+2 it finds more results but often wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the filtering implemented in the example you gave is quite naive. Suppose you get one match with a really high score (w.r.t the distance between the descriptors), then `min_dist` is really small and possibly filters out good matches. In other words, matches having the best score are not necessarily the best geometrically (two features can look really similar but not be a real-world correspondence)...

What you can try to do is:

- Remove the filtering implementation; keep all of the matches
- Compute the homography matrix using `findHomography()`

  - `findHomography()` allows you to use a `mask` in order to keep track of the inliers
- Draw only the matches that are marked as inliers in `mask`

This should be a better validation.